# Why is Freeth's nephroid called a nephroid?

Tags: geometry

A nephroid is an epycloid that can be generated by rolling a circle on the outside of a circle with doubled radius.
It was called by Richard Proctor (1878) because its shape looks like a kidney (see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Nephroid.html).

A nephroid of Freeth (called from Thomas Jacob Freeth, 1879) is a strophoid of the circle and has nothing to do with Proctor's nephroid (from what I undertand) and doesn't look like a kidney, nor Proctor's nephroid (see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FreethsNephroid.html)

So: why is Freeth's nephroid called a nephroid ?

Note: I could not find the original paper of Freeth where he may have explained the name.

Comment: The original "paper" is a summary in the [Appendix to vol. 10 of the Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society (1878)](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/plms/s1-10.1.225), p. 228ff. It gives no explanations for the naming. Perhaps, Freeth and Proctor had different ideas about the shape of the kidney :)

Comment: @Conifold And what is on p. 130?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Just a mention with Freeth's name and title. It seems that Proctor had in mind the shape of a pair of kidneys, while Freeth the shape of a single kidney.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Doesn't look like a kidney?

Freeth's nephroid
[image: Freeth]$\qquad$[image: kidney]

Comment: Well, I guess it's all about imagination. And indeed with the two figures it can be better understood. Thanks :)